# With Spring 3.1, How do you test urls for your controllers?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, controller

In prior versions of spring (3.0), it was possible to test your controllers via the correct urls using the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter and HandlerMapping objects in the ApplicationContext. However, in Spring 3.1, things have changed and the code I used to use to make this work no longer functions.

How do you test Spring controller urls in Spring 3.1? For example, I'd like to write code that looks like this:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = handle("GET", "/businesses");
```

That way I'm testing my mappings in addition to the controller's action logic.

In particular, I am most interested in making sure that I can pass session attributes and have them correctly passed to my controller actions's @Valid annotation.

Is there any way to accomplish this with Spring 3.1?

This is the code I was using:

```
protected ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    final HandlerMapping handlerMapping = applicationContext.getBean(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class);

    final HandlerExecutionChain handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
    assertNotNull("No handler found for request, check you request mapping", handler);

    final Object controller = handler.getHandler();

    final HandlerInterceptor[] interceptors = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getInterceptors();
    for (HandlerInterceptor interceptor : interceptors) {
        final boolean carryOn = interceptor.preHandle(request, response, controller);
        if (!carryOn) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
}

protected ModelAndView handle(String method, String path, String queryString) throws Exception {
    request.setMethod(method);
    request.setRequestURI(path);

    if(queryString != null) {
        String[] parameters = queryString.split("&");
        for(String parameter : parameters) {
            String[] pair = parameter.split("=");
            if(pair.length == 2) {
                request.setParameter(pair[0], pair[1]);
            } else {
                request.setParameter(pair[0], "");
            }
        }
    }

    return handle(request, response);
}

protected ModelAndView handle(String method, String path, String attribute, Object object) throws Exception {
    MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
    session.setAttribute(attribute, object);
    request.setSession(session);

    return handle(method, path, null);
}

protected ModelAndView handle(String method, String path) throws Exception {
    return handle(method, path, null);
}

protected void assertContentType(ModelAndView modelAndView, String contentType) {
    assertEquals(contentType, modelAndView.getView().getContentType());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me instead recommend [spring-test-mvc](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc) which is currently in 1.0.0M1 but is planned to be packaged with newer Spring MVC versions. It should be able to handle the cases that you are looking for quite easily, your test would end up looking like this:

```
xmlConfigSetup("classpath:/META-INF/spring/web/webmvc-config.xml")
            .configureWebAppRootDir("src/main/webapp", false).build()
            .perform(get("/businesses").param("name", "param1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("viewname"));
```

Your test does look appropriate for 3.1, so if you still want to continue with your approach can you point exactly what is not working - it sounds like normal requests are going through but the session attributes don't seem to be binding?

Comment: Yes, the session attributes are not binding correctly. This approach used to work in Spring 3.0 just fine, but it has stopped working. Could it be a bug? The objects being passed into the controller seem to be empty instances now. Using the spring-test-mvc approach, can I pass session objects like before? If so, I have no problem switching. The project is only 2 days old - I haven't written a lot of code yet. I am still figuring things out before I go full-steam ahead.

Comment: Doubt if it could be a bug - the Spring MVC code has changed quite a bit between 3.0 and 3.1, the handler is no longer the controller, it is actually the final `@RequestMapped` method. Your code is further not correct for Spring 3.0 as `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` was introduced only with 3.1.0. I am assuming that session attributes should correctly with mvc-test - here is a sample - https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/server/samples/standalone/resultmatchers/SessionAttributeAssertionTests.java

Comment: Here is a little more info on this project - http://rossenstoyanchev.org/blog/2012/06/28/early-milestone-of-spring-test-mvc/

Comment: The reason my code looks like 3.1.0 is that I've been trying to get it to work for 3.1. The code before was taken from a 3.0 project, so please trust me - it used to work just fine. The only reason I changed it is because it stop working. It only "sort of" worked when I made the changes above - but it still doesn't work for attributes (which is a big problem). I will just use the new spring mvc testing framework. There's no reason not to as far as I can see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the test cases I used with Spring 3.1. Hope it can meet your requirement.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml" })
public class ControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handleAdapter;

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;
    @Test
    public void playerControllerTest() throws Exception{

        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        request.setRequestURI("/players.show");
        request.setMethod("GET");

        Object handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
        ModelAndView mav = handleAdapter.handle(request, response,handler);

        ModelAndViewAssert.assertViewName(mav,"players");

    }

}
```

Comment: This is actually extremely similar to the code I am using. It does not work if you put an object into the session attributes. The session will not correctly bind to the action. Instead, the object seems to be a newly created one.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://rstoyanchev.github.com/spring-31-and-mvc-test/#1) is a very nice presentation which talks about testing Spring 3.1 classes and controller, following is an example:

```
@Test
public void testSave() {

    Account account = new Account();
    BindingResult result = 
        new BeanPropertyBindingResult(account, "account");

    AccountManager mgr = createMock(AccountManager.class);
    mgr.saveOrUpdate(account);
    replay(mgr);

    AccountController contrlr = new AccountController(mgr);

    String view = contrlr.save(account, result);

    assertEquals("redirect:accounts", view);
    verify(mgr);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm very aware that you can call the controller's methods like any other pojo, but this does not test the mappings. So if the mappings are wrong, they will go untested until you try it out in tomcat. I would rather have regression testing on the mappings in addition to testing the controller's logic